# div inside other div, moving down in relation to scroll (React)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, animation, scroll

I want to have an object falling from the sky while scrolling down the page. The idea is: You have the `object div` not moving. It should be in the center of the page (50 px from the top of its parent) and when you scroll down it should scroll down too.

**Whats the catch?** The `object` is in another `div`. I only want the `object` to be visible inside this `div`. So not on the entire website.

**What have I tried?** 
**1:** Fixed positioning, but then it shows up on the `entire page`, `z-index` does not work with `fixed`. 
**2:** `Relative` positioning on the `parent` and `absolute` on the child but then the `object div` does not go down the page when I scroll.

**Visual representation::**
[image]

**On scroll down:**
[image]

**React Component:**

```
<div className="container">
      <div className="container--object">
          <img src={object}/>
      </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.container--object {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
}
```

My parent component is the homepage. And the `siblings` of this react component are other `div's`. The functionality to make the div move down the page is what I am struggling with, how can I move the `object div` down? Is there a way to base it off the top of the browser?

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried code wise.

Comment: You should post a minimal reproducible example of the code you tried to use

Comment: @LouisDurand I pasted the code I am working with, I have been struggling and deleting a lot of code. This is all I have now, hence I need to find a way to move the `top` value of the `object` as I scroll.

Comment: @alesssz Yeah sorry, I have so little and it doesn't do much, but it added it.

Comment: @Otto so you want the div to remain still. Then when the page is scrolled down, the div should always remain at 50px from top no matter how you scroll down?

Comment: @alesssz As I scroll I want the `div` to scroll down, but I want it to start at `50px` from the `top`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok if i understood correctly, you want something like this? I used an image and some test text

```css
.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 2500px;
  position: relative;
}

.container_object {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="container_object">
          <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" />
      </div>
      <div style="position: absolute; top:500px">
        TEEEEEEEEEEEEST 111111111
      </div>
      
      <div style="position: absolute; top:800px">
        TEEEEEEEEEEEEST 222222222
      </div>
</div>
```

You should see this snippet in full page

Comment: It is close to what I want. The problem I am facing is that the `object div` is showing on the entire website. Not just only within the `container div`.

Comment: Ok... somehow changing the `z-index` on the `container-object` to `-1` works. Before it didnt, now it does!! Thanks!

Comment: My only problem now is that other divs that are in the `container` are no longer clickable. Like buttons, eventhough they appear above my `object div`.

Comment: Basically, if I add a background to the `container` I need to change its `z-index` to `-2` otherwise the `object div` appears behind it. But then it also makes all my items within my `container` not work on `hover` or `click`. Because it has a negative `z-index`

Comment: If I keep the `z-index` of the container 1, and then the `z-index` of the object 2. Then it works, however then my object div is again visible on the entire site.

Comment: "Solved it" by making other containers on page have a `z-index` of `3`. Bit hacky though.

Comment: @Otto a bit of hacky but that's what z-index is made for :)